# Multidimensional array - How can I get this to work from a function?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a sets of information in a multidimensional array like so:

```
$slides = array (
    array (
        'link' => 'page.php',
        'image' => 'image1.jpg',
        'alt' => 'text for alt' 
    ),
    array (
        'link' => 'anotherpage.php',
        'image' => 'image2.jpg',
        'alt' => 'text for alt' 
    )
);
```

Which currently works using:

```
foreach($slides as $slide => $data){
    echo "<a href=\"{$data['link']}\">
        <img src=\"{$data['image']}\" alt=\"{$data['alt']}\" />
        </a>";
}
```

Now, my question is: **how in the world do I get this to work as a function?**

```
function createSlides($slides){ /* foreach loop */ }
```

I tried this but I think I'm misunderstanding how to pass the array since it's a language construct and not an object. This is my first time working with a multidimensional array. *Also, I was thinking I could control what `$data` goes in with the function argument, i.e. `echo createSlides($slides[1,2,4]);`*. Am I misunderstanding this, or is it just because the array isn't passing into the function?

Comment: Have you tried it...?  Arrays pass around just fine.  I do it all the time.  The only thing they don't do that objects do is let you modify them in a way the caller can see, and even that's fixable by passing by reference.

Comment: I don't know what changed, but it does work now. What about controlling the `$data`, how could I do this? `echo sliderContent($slides[1,2]);` breaks the code.

Comment: Of course it does.  PHP doesn't do slices like that.  :P  You need to call some function that only returns the stuff you want.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE: You'd make a new array only containing the elements you want, look at [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice).

Comment: @cHao I've only been learning php for 2 months - your sarcasm has no power here ;) Ah, okay, it takes a new array - now it makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE: What sarcasm?  There's a bit of snark, perhaps, but no sarcasm.  :)  The snark's mostly because all of this is either covered in the PHP manual, or is common sense.  Even as odd as PHP is, most of the basics still apply in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are asking for this, but just like a normal parameter:

```
function createSlides($slides){
   foreach($slides as $slide => $data){
       echo "<a href=\"{$data['link']}\">
          <img src=\"{$data['image']}\" alt=\"{$data['alt']}\" />
       </a>";
   }
}

createSlides($slides);
```

Comment: For the second part of the question, you could pass a second parameter, for instance `function createSlides($slides, $filter = array()) { ... }` and then simply put this line before the loop: `if !empty($filter) $slides = array_diff_key($slides, $filter);` - so now you could just pass a bunch of indexes you want to be printed: `createSlides($slides, array(0,2));` would print only the first and the third slide.

Comment: I like that method for this situation, makes it much easier to configure it as needed. @Quasdunk Thanks

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE You're welcome. Please note that the second parameter is optional, you don't have to pass it when calling the function. If it's not passed/specified (or has the pre-defined value), all slides are printed. This concept is an equivalent to `overloaded functions` you might know from other languages like Java or C#. **@Steve:** Please feel free to put this in your answer so it covers the whole question :)